# rails - append to activerecord results

Tags: ruby-on-rails

A user has many followers.

I have a method in my users model that looks like this

```
def user_profile
    ret = Hash.new
    ret[:id] = id
    ret[:name] = name
    ret[:username] = username
    ret[:bio] = bio
    ret[:email] = email
    ret
  end
```

I would like to include whether the current_user is following the user being returned or not. Obviously "following" is not a field in the database but I have a table that stores users and who they follow. How can I efficiently append to every user whether the current users followers includes them or not?

Maybe doing a map or going through each user result in my controller?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create one to many association between your user model and following method. While generating following model add User:belongs_to after adding fields of following method.

Comment: I have this as my user model class `Follower < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user, counter_cache: :following_count
  belongs_to :connection, class_name: "User", counter_cache: :followers_count
  validates_presence_of :user_id, :connection_id
end`
What is the syntax for what I'm trying to accomplish?

Comment: See my answers. I got it to work but it seems inneficient.

Comment: Please give me brief code of you user model and following model. So I can help you properly.

Comment: the entire follower model is 2 comments above. Here are the relevant properties in the user model:   `has_many :followers, dependent: :destroy  `

Answer (score 0):

I ended up making it work like this but I don't think it's the most efficient way.

Basically get all the people the current user is following and see if the users in the users array match the id and put a true for following.

```
following = Follower.where(user_id: current_user.id)

      users = users.map do |user_record|
    user_record.as_json.tap do |user|
    user[:following] = following.any? {|follower| follower.connection_id == user_record.id}
    end
```